# C# - How to download SOAP Attachment using ResponseSoapContext

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I'm consuming a **Java Web Service** from my C# Application. I have to invoke a method and read results from SOAP attachment. For me it's first time with **SOAP** attachment.

I invoke my method successfully, but I have problems to read results.

I understand that I must use this object:

```
myWebService.ResponseSoapContext.Attachments[0].Stream
```

But I don't understand how to read the content. It's base-64 encoded?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved...

```
                    Stream stream = ws.ResponseSoapContext.Attachments[0].Stream;    

                //XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

                wsXmlOutput = sr.ReadToEnd();
```